# iOS キーボードが表示・非表示の状態を取得したい。

Tags: swift, ios

iOS10.11で、キーボードが表示・非表示の状態を取得したい。

キーボードが表示されている場合と、非表示の場合で処理を処理を分けたいです。

Answer (score 1):

```swift
// 変数用意しておく
var isShown = false

// viewDidLoadなどで監視を設定
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidAppear), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidDisappear), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)

フラグを切り替える
@objc func keyboardDidAppear() {
    isShown = true
}
@objc func keyboardDidDisappear() {
    isShown = false
}

if isShown {
    // キーボードが表示されている時
} else {
    // 隠れている時
}
```